# How do I replace a value with an apostrophe in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in R, just have a couple of months using this software.

In a dataframe, I have some values with an apostrophe and I would like to change it to another word.

I tried this:

`data$HomeTeam[data$HomeTeam=="M'Gladbach"]<-"Gladbach"`

but I get a Warning Message:

`In [<-.factor(*tmp*, dta$HomeTeam == "M'Gladbach", value = c(2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `data$HomeTeam` is a `?factor` and you are trying to replace it with a `?character` hence the warning and `NA`

Comment: Are you trying to replace it with a totally different word or as shown in the example remove only the prefix part including the apostrophe?

Comment: @rawr - there's nothing necessarily wrong with using a character to replace a factor value, so long as the character aligns perfectly with an existing factor level, which it doesn't here. One could even just modify one of the `levels` of the variable to change it from `"M'Gladbach"` to `"Gladbach"`

Comment: @thelatemail well you are using a character string to "replace" an integer and it seems like you can replace a factor with a string like you say because `[<-.factor` is hiding the details, so i would be inclined to respectfully disagree with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `sub`

```
data$HomeTeam <- sub("^[^']*'", "", data$HomeTeam)
data$HomeTeam
#[1] "Gladbach"  "Sonja"     "Henderson" "Marshall"
```

The `sub` output will be 'character' class.  If we need to retain the 'factor' class, you can try `sub` on the levels of 'HomeTeam' and assign the output back to 'levels' (as showed in the comments by @thelatemail)

```
levels(data$HomeTeam) <- sub("^[^']*'","",levels(data$HomeTeam))
```

If you want to replace only the word "M'Gladbach" with "Gladbach" as showed in the post, it is better to convert the "HomeTeam" column from `factor` to `character` class.  It may be better to read the dataset with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option in `read.table/read.csv` or in the `data.frame`.

As the "HomeTeam" column is already a factor, you can use `as.character` (from @rawr's comment)

```
 data$HomeTeam <- as.character(data$HomeTeam)
 data$HomeTeam[data$HomeTeam=="M'Gladbach"]<-"Gladbach"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(22)
data <- data.frame(HomeTeam= c("M'Gladbach", "S'Sonja", 
             "HR'Henderson", "Marshall"), Value=rnorm(4))
```

Comment: `levels(data$HomeTeam) <- sub(".*?'","",levels(data$HomeTeam))` if you want to retain the data as a `factor`